# Call function based on input

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I've an textbox in asp.net,when i enter ";" semicolon in textbox means it have to call a function.Is there any way to do this.please help me out guys..i tried change function but it calls at every keypress in textbox.

```
$('#prgrp').on('change', function (evt)
            {
                var txt = $("#prgrp").val();
                var valueArray = txt.split(';');
                var valueSortArray = valueArray.sort();
                var duplicateValues = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < valueSortArray.length; i++)
                {                     
                    if (valueSortArray[i + 1] == valueSortArray[i])
                    {
                     duplicateValues.push(valueSortArray[i]);                            
                    }
                }
                if (duplicateValues.length > 0)
                {
                 $("#duplicate").html("Don't enter repeated values");
                 $('#duplicate').css('color', 'RED');
                 $("#prgrp").autocomplete("disable");
             }
             else {
                 $("#duplicate").html("");
                 $("#prgrp").autocomplete("enable");
             }
         });
```

Comment: Show some code,what  you have already tried!

Comment: i posted my code rahul.

Comment: Did my answer helped you? If so do accept it as answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:-

```
$("#prgrp").keypress(function (e) {
     if (e.keyCode == 59) {
         //Call your function here
     }
});
```

Please note, you can also use `e.which` in place of `e.keyCode` as it is jquery standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#prgrp').bind('keypress', function(e) {
var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
 if(code == 59) { //
   //Do something
 }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/gayanstar/0ojL8t8x/)

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$( "#prgrp" ).keypress(function( event ) {
    if ( event.which == 59 || event.keycode == 59 ) {
        //your function call
    }
});
```